# Why am I getting this error from babel on my server hosted on AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, babeljs

I'm getting the below error when trying to run a script in my EC2 instance.

There were no changes to the codebase but it's giving this error since a couple of days. It appears to be an error generating due to code inside the *pg* module but why would it do that if I hadn't upgraded the module version?

I upgraded the node version of this instance to the 16 thinking that it might be because of my node version being too low.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:74
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/utils.js: 'return' outside of function. (7:2)

   5 |   // We are on an old version of Node.js that requires legacy crypto utilities.
   6 |   module.exports = require('./utils-legacy')
>  7 |   return
     |   ^
   8 | }
   9 |
  10 | const nodeCrypto = require('crypto')
    at instantiate (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error/credentials.ts:62:21)
    at toParseError (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error.ts:60:12)
    at Parser.raise (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.ts:1490:19)
    at Parser.parseReturnStatement (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1020:12)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:478:21)
    at Parser.parseStatementLike (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:417:17)
    at Parser.parseStatementListItem (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:366:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1360:16)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1333:10)
    at Parser.parseBlock (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1301:10)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:547:21)
    at Parser.parseStatementLike (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:417:17)
    at Parser.parseStatementOrSloppyAnnexBFunctionDeclaration (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.                                                                                     ts:386:17)
    at Parser.parseIfStatement (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1011:28)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:476:21)
    at Parser.parseStatementLike (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:417:17)
    at Parser.parseModuleItem (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:354:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1359:16)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1333:10)
    at Parser.parseProgram (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:226:10)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:208:25)
    at Parser.parse (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/index.ts:45:10)
    at parse (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.ts:67:38)
    at parser (/node_modules/@babel/core/src/parser/index.ts:28:19)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile (/node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/normalize-file.ts:51:24)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/index.ts:38:36)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:29:20)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
    at fn (/node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
    at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (/node_modules/@babel/core/src/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.ts:97                                                                                     :14)
    at Object.transformSync (/node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
    at transformSync (/node_modules/@babel/register/src/worker/transform.js:94:33)
    at Function.handleMessage (/node_modules/@babel/register/src/worker/handle-message.js:15:16)
    at LocalClient.<anonymous> (/node_modules/@babel/register/src/worker-client.js:103:27)
    at LocalClient.transform (/node_modules/@babel/register/src/worker-client.js:40:16)
    at compile (/node_modules/@babel/register/src/hook.js:57:25)
    at compileBabel7 (/node_modules/@babel/register/src/hook.js:48:14)
    at Module._compile (/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:130:29)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:141:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/sasl.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14) {
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
  reasonCode: 'IllegalReturn',
  loc: Position { line: 7, column: 2, index: 284 },
  pos: [Getter/Setter]
}
```